# Arrays.sort doesn't sort my list

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have an arraylist and I want to use arrays.sort to sort them alphabetically, but when I run the app, the list is totally not sorted. I am not sure what's wrong.

```
public class AList extends ListActivity {
    static String[] People = new String[] {
            "John Ken",
            "Albert Chan",
            "Kelvin McDonald"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Arrays.sort(People);}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alist);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        People));
```

Comment: How do you think it must sort? Give the expected output.

Comment: why you have a main method in your activity?!

Comment: And what makes you think it has executed? And what makes you think the array isn't sorted afterwards? With this code you cannot possibly tell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think your `main` method executes (Android has its own `main` method).

Try calling `Arrays.sort()` in your `onCreate` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

`public static void main(String[] args)`

**Android doesn't have any main() method.**

**-** `onCreate()` is considered as the **entry point** of any Android Program.

**-** so you can use `Arrays.sort()` in `onCreate` or in **any appropriate place in the program.**